# Regex for text between two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get some text between two strings in C# in regex expression.
The text is in variable (`tb1.product_name`) : `Example Text | a:10,Colour:Green`

1. Get all text before `|`, in this case, `Example Text`
2. Get all text between `:` and `,`, in this case, `10`

In two differents regex.
I try with:

`Regex.Match(tb1.product_name, @"\:([^,]*)\)").Groups[1].Value`

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Is it necessary to use regex?

Comment: I agree that regex is not necessary and probably makes it more complex. The answer suggests substring and indexof, and I'd also recommend looking at split. You could then split the string up into an array of values that may make it easier to work with. Split on the pipe and you have the string and value. Then split the value on the comma and you have the array of values. Then you could split on the colon and you have your key/value. It just depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If it is **not so necessary** to use regex, you can do this simply by using `string.Substring` & `string.IndexOf`:

```
string str = "Example Text | a:10,Colour:Green";
string strBeforeVerticalBar = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('|'));
string strInBetweenColonAndComma = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(':') + 1, str.IndexOf(',') - str.IndexOf(':') - 1);
```

**Edit 1:**

I feel `Regex` might be an overkill for something as simple as this. Also if use what i suggested, you can add `Trim()` at the end to remove *whitespaces*, if any. Like:

```
string strBeforeVerticalBar = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('|')).Trim();
string strInBetweenColonAndComma = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(':') + 1, str.IndexOf(',') - str.IndexOf(':') - 1).Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = @"Example Text |a:10,Colour: Green";
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"^([A-Za-z\s]*)|$");
Match match2= Regex.Match(str, @":([0-9]*),");
//output Example Text
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
//output 10
Console.WriteLine(match2.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: And how get Green ??